# codeIgniter load view at wrong place

Tags: codeigniter

I write this code in codeigniter

```
        $this->load->view('view_test_header');
        echo "Hi";
        $this->load->view('view_test_footer');
```

and get this html source code

```
Hi<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

<style>
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
</style>        
</head>

<body>
<div style="width:900px;height:500px;margin:5px auto;background-color:#3d3d3d;padding:10px 5px;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The "Hi" word must be in the div tag.
Please help.

Comment: Create a view content and put your "hi" inside and then load it after your header. I'm not sure, but I think your code doesn't work because CI doen't output the view  as soon as you load it. It does that later in the runtime so your echo "hi" is executed before the load->view(). And for the record, you should not have echos within a controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load it as another view:

```
$this->load->view('view_test_header');
$this->load->view('hi');
$this->load->view('view_test_footer');
```

where the file `hi.php` could simply contain the word

`Hi`

or

`<?php echo 'Hi'; ?>`

Even better, you could pass the text as a parameter to the view:

```
$data['display_text'] = 'Hi';
$this->load->view('view_test_header');
$this->load->view('hi',$data);
$this->load->view('view_test_footer');
```

OK, editing to reflect what I guess is your file structure, though you don't explain it specifically:

In `view_test_header.php`:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

    <style>
    *{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    </style>        
    </head>

    <body>
```

In `view_test_footer.php`:

```
</body>
</html>
```

Then, in `hi.php`:

```
<div style="width:900px;height:500px;margin:5px auto;background-color:#3d3d3d;padding:10px 5px;">
<?php echo $display_text; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: In your example, `hi.php` should start after `<body>` (which belongs to the header view) and should end before `</body>` (footer view)